# Sorting mysql array value after string chars swapped from fetched DB data

Tags: mysql, string, sorting, arrays

I want to sort one column fetched from mysql DB, and stored in an array. After fetching I am doing below steps.

1. DB Fetching fields array in row format. 
       ->Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5
2. From that fields array One columns data [Field3], swapping string keywords. 
   eg.
   `AB013, DB131, RS001`
   should become:
   `013AB, 131DB, 001RS`

Now I want to sort above value in new string format
    like-> 001RS, 013AB, 131DB

Its not like that, fix number for swapping string. To split and join string again there is a dynamic value which allow fetch data string to split that string from the given character position and then sort it again with new name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you let the DB do the work (for the fixed position data in your example):

```
select Field1
     , Field2
     , concat(  substr(Field3,3,3) 
               ,substr(Field3,1,2)
             ) as SwapedField3
     , Field4
     , Field5
from Table
order by SwapedField3
```

However, this doesn't take the 'dynamic value' for the split position into account...

- Where does that value come from?
- Can it be deduced from the data somehow?

Comment: In my case there are lots of unique code in string format, which needs to swapping and reorder in list mode.
# Now here Unique code & Line code comes from DB, Line code being reference for splitting string & concat string of unique code.
# To split string char. no. value also comes from DB and stored with Line code reference.

Comment: @Shail Patel: But couldn't you use that 'line code' to parameterize the "subste()" function, if you use the length() function? something like
 `substr(Field3,LineCode,length(Field3) - LineCode)`

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
  select 
    Field1,
    Field2,
    CASE Field3
      WHEN 'AB013' THEN '013AB'
      WHEN 'DB131' THEN '131DB'
      WHEN 'RS001' THEN '001RS'
    END CASE AS NewField3,
    Field4,
    Field5 
  from Table1 
)
order by NewField3
```